# One or more import cycles would need to be created to compile this component, which is not supported by the current compiler configuration

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular12

I have an old angular library and when I migrate to `angular 12` and try to build my library I am getting the below error:

```
  projects/namespace/lin-folder/src/lib/components/alerts/alerts.component.ts:7:1
      7 @Component({
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
      8   selector: 'app-alerts',
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ... 
     39 
        
     40 }
        ~
    The component 'AlertsComponent' is used in the template but importing it would create a cycle: projects/namespace/lin-folder//src/lib/components/header/header.component.ts -> projects/namespace/lin-folder/src/lib/components/alerts/alerts.component.ts -> projects/namespace/lin-folder//src/lib/website.module.ts -> projects/namespace/lin-folder/src/lib/components/header/header.component.ts
```

Did anyone face the same kind of error?

Comment: Did you reimport component in any other places rather than app.module?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58749172/angular-circular-dependency-warning

Comment: No, i think I got the problem

Comment: This answer solved this problem for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61127062/349169

Answer (score 5):

The problem was I have an `interface` declared in my `Library` main `module` and one of my components imported that `interface`. So I have to move the `interface` to a new file and share it both in the modules file and component file.

Below is the Module code which is shared in the component

```
export interface WebsiteEnvironment {. // as this in the module file and imported in one of the component, it created the problem
  restUrl?: string;
  alertDelayInSeconds?: number;
  loginUrl: string;
  allowTokenToAllDomain?: string;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class WebsiteModule {
  public static forRoot(websiteEnvironment: WebsiteEnvironment): ModuleWithProviders<WebsiteModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: WebsiteModule,
      providers: [
        ...
      ]
    };
  }

  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: WebsiteModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error(
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

Simply removed the interface. create a new file and add that interface. share the interface import in both module and component will remove the circular dependency

Comment: This was a solution to my problem aswell. I had a variable that weas being exported in module and caused the problem. Moved that variable to another file and worker properly

Comment: I had the same issue, because I imported one module to common module and two times in other modules. I removed two other import, and all work well.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue with a simple component and directive inside a library.
The directive injects the component, and the component uses this directive in the template. So a typescript import cycle is introduced.

resizable.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-resizable',
  template: `<div [resizableGlyph]="['top', 'start']"></div>`
})
export class ResizableComponent {}
```

resizable-glyph.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ResizableComponent } from '../resizable/resizable.component';
export type Position = 'top' | 'end' | 'bottom' | 'start';

@Directive({ selector: '[resizableGlyph]' })
export class ResizableGlyphDirective {
  constructor(private resizable: ResizableComponent) { }

  @Input('resizableGlyph') positions: Position[] = [];
}
```

- [Here is the error](https://angular.io/errors/NG3003), but sadly the docs only show the scenario
- [Here is information](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export) on how to solve it

To solve this, I had to use `import type`

resizable.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-resizable',
  template: `<div [resizableGlyph]="['top', 'start']"></div>`,
  providers: [
    { provide: 'RESIZABLE', useExisting: ResizableComponent }
  ]
})
export class ResizableComponent {}
```

resizable-glyph.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, Inject, Input } from '@angular/core';
// Below solves the import cycle
import type { ResizableComponent } from '../resizable/resizable.component';
export type Position = 'top' | 'end' | 'bottom' | 'start';

@Directive({ selector: '[resizableGlyph]' })
export class ResizableGlyphDirective {
  constructor(@Inject('RESIZABLE') private resizable: ResizableComponent) { }
  @Input('resizableGlyph') positions: Position[] = [];
}
```

[Commit reference](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/angular-library-import-cycles/commit/ec23566052cd613b84bec583aa7b3e45bfbacb4b)

Now you'll have problems running your jest unit tests. To solve this you need to do [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75999885/cant-run-unit-tests-when-using-type-only-imports/76002909#76002909)

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2022

We faced this problem because we had a import statement that looked like

```
import { myUtilFunc } from "../../"
```

This was added by vscode automatically when auto importing & was working fine during `ng serve` as well as `ng serve --prod`.

We had to change the import statement to

```
import { myUtilFunc } from "../../utils"
```

and the build resolved after it

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error when I was building a library.

To fix it I changed in `tsconfig.lib.prod.json` the option of `enableIvy` to be true

Comment: enableIvy=true indeed removes the error, however, does not allow to publish the library to npm.